# Separating out homogeneous and inhomogeneous parts

Tags: differential-equations

This is probably very simple to do but I am getting confused. Consider the following differential eqn

```
f = y'[x] - 3 y[x] + 5 x*Exp[-x];
```

I want to separate the homo and inhomo part. First I am trying to find $f$ when $y=0$. That will be the inhomo part and we can then subtract the inhomo part from the differential eqn to find out the homo part. But when I write

```
f = f /. y -> 0
```

it is giving `5 x*Exp[-x] - 3 0[x]`. How to remove this `0[x]` without writing `0[x] -> 0`?

Comment: The `InputForm` of the expression for `f` is `(5*x)/E^x - 3*y[x] + Derivative[1][y][x]`. So you could use `{y[x]->0,Derivative[_][y][x]->0}` for the replacement rule.

Comment: `Cases[f, x_ /; FreeQ[x, y]]` will yield the homogeneous part

Comment: `f /.  y -> (0 &)` also gives the inhomogenous part